# Oracle Apex 5.0 dynamic actions setting page items

Tags: oracle, dynamic, action, oracle-apex

I am trying to retrieve one text value from a textfield on the samepage to an other.

I am using a dynamic action onclick for a button this fires the folEncountering lots of bugs…

With dynamic actions cant access the values of existing page items all seems to be empty. I tried nvl(:P3_TO, :P3_FROM) but this doesnt do shit.

Also i noticed that setting a label on a button it doesnt show up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apex 5 : Dynamic action set page item value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756037/apex-5-dynamic-action-set-page-item-value)