# How do I get the value of a select item from a page without submitting in Apex 5?

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I wish to have the user make a choice in a select box and then in a Dymamic Action which waits for the select box to be changed it reads the select box value that was chosen

Comment: Well, this could mean a whole lot of things :p Aren't you just looking for the "Change" event on the select list item, which will trigger when the value has changed?

Comment: when you say Change event, do you mean the Change Dynamic Action?

Comment: yes: this DA is action is for the javascript change event. When an item gets changed in value, this event fires. Eg select another entry from a select list.

Comment: This is what I did, but there is no way to get the value from the select list at this point and insert it into another field, or can it be done with javascript. If you add the answer I will mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a Dynamic Action which fires on "Change". 
As a true action:

- Action: "Set Value"
- Set Type: "JavaScript Expression"
- Javascript Expression: `apex.item(this.triggeringElement).getValue()`
- Choose the item to set the value with under "Affected Elements"

This will get the value of the element which triggered the change event and will set it to the affected element you choose.
Note though: the value of the select list will be the underlying return value (eg ID), NOT the display value.

Comment: Are you in the Apex slack channel too?